# How do I create an animation without noticeable loops?

Tags: ai, skeletal-animation

I'd like to create vivid idle and passive animations for a creature, but I want to avoid the appearance of obvious loops in the animation and avoid the use of obviously-identifiable pre-baked animation clips.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Which engine do you want to use? Or is this a general question about the theoretical concept?

Comment: Are you animating sprites or 3D models?

Comment: One technique [used in Uncharted](http://gdcvault.com/play/1012300/Animation-and-Player-Control-in) was to have a short base animation for each action, then layer it with a longer additive animation, consisting of a little wiggle and shifting of balance. By keeping the lengths of the animations relatively prime, it can take much longer before the combined result repeats exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Make your animation duration the Least Common Multiple of varying loop times. For example, to make a looping atom animation, with a nucleus and 3 'electrons', I might have 3 spheres rotating around a center. Each orbit would have a different period.

Electron 1: 1 sec orbit

Electron 2: 2 sec orbit

Electron 3: 3 sec orbit

Using the LCM method, we'd arrive at a loop length of 6 seconds. This loop will be much more subtle than if they all looped over 3 seconds.

One other thing to note is to make sure that your start and end frames are not identical - meaning.. If you animate from 0 degree rotation to 360 degree rotation over 60 frames, your loop is really 0-59. Your final frame of the loop should be the frame before you're back to start. Otherwise, you'd have a duplicated frame in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to make sure there are common start and end points of the animations to link them together smoothly. You could choose to have all animations start and end at exactly the same point, however this might be fairly obvious. You could have a few start and end points, with multiple animations for all the start and end points, this should minimize the looping effect.

Answer (score 0):

[MotionBuilder](http://www.autodesk.com/products/motionbuilder/overview) is a good tool for cleaning up animations to make nice cycles.

Failing that: if it's just an idle animation, you could just ping-pong the animation to avoid glitches. That is, when you get to the end of the animation start playing backwards until you get to the beginning and then start playing it forwards again. It's a clumsy hack but might work for some anims.

Answer (score 0):

Procedurally vary the timing of your animation frames. Instead of having each animation always take the same time, randomize the duration a bit. For example, if the character's idle animation is simply turning their head left and right, randomized timing will give the appearance that the character's view sometimes lingers on things, sometimes sways casually through the landscape and sometimes twitches nervously because they thought they saw something.

While I would certainly not suggest doing that for running (where any irregularity in rhythm would look unnatural) or more active actions like attacking (where timing is too important to be left to chance), it can help to make a simple idle animation look more natural.

Another thing you can do to make idling look more natural is to have multiple idle animations and cycle them in a random order.

Comment: That reminds me of Bioshock Infinite. There the idle animations only played as long as a character was in view. This way, the cance of seeing the same part of a longer animation repeatedly is much lower, as the NPC will pause until it is looked at again, ensuring the user sees all the animation frames before the loop-around happens.

Comment: Bioshock Infinite also marked certain spots in the maps as interesting. So if you idled there, your character or NPCs would turn towards certain objects, track them with their gazes, or maybe even poke them. Having your character perform the same motion with a different object also makes it seem less like a loop.